# attach information to automatically updated date row

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet with the top row showing dates and the left hand side with job ID's. In the columns beneath the dates I have shaded cells to show which job is happening during that week.

The top row automatically updates to the week commence date. The shaded cells i would like to automatically update as the date changes. Eg next monday column b is effectively deleted and the shaded cells currently in column c move to column b. I stiill want to be able to manually change shading cells too. IU attch a spreadhseet and a screenshot.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14OIbyzlUwaPr3bQ0p8L1djNd-gSA5I7uVhRVIKcJQE0/edit#gid=0s

Comment: your sheet requires access authorization !

Comment: Hi and welcome to WebApps. Your question is written as if a volunteer had your spreadsheet open as they read your question. You shouldn’t expect volunteers to have to open your spreadsheet to understand your question. In fact, questions should be capable of standing alone, whether or not a spreadsheet is supplied. Would you please edit your question to describe your scenario and explain exactly what your problem is. Even though you have linked your spreadsheet, you might choose to include a screenshot to complement your question.

Comment: As I understand it, as each week passes, you want to remove the expired week. So, how about a onOpen script that tests if the current date is >= week#2 start date, if yes, then delete column B; if no, do nothing.

Of course, deleting Column B removes any historical value attached to that data. E.g. how long has this job been running, etc. so you might choose to archive Column B rather than delete it.

Comment: Hi. 
Danielle. I change the sheet permission. 
Tedinoz - Would that mean that each week on say Monday when I log on the sheet has updated.?If so, I dont know how to do that anyway.